# How to automatically rename image uploads?

Tags: url

How to automatically rename the image files to a random string during the upload process? For example, I have an image named "big_poster.jpg" and I want it to be saved as something random, for example "2680542675157_cc7m541v_l.jpg"

I see every asset have a "Filename" and "Title" field. Would be possible to use these fields to generate a random string? Perhaps using the [Randomm](https://github.com/sjelfull/Craft-Randomm/) plugin?

Comment: Curiously, what's the use case for this?

Comment: I'd like this as well. I have users adding photos from the front end and it would be nice to be able to organise them automatically as I have no control over what there original files are named.

Comment: @shorn Exactly!

Comment: Where to put that code? Can I create just an empty module with that code? because tried but nothing...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11326)

Answer (score 2):

## Use the assets.onBeforeSaveAsset event

You could write a plugin that listens for when an asset is saved via the `assets.onBeforeSaveAsset` event and rename the image before it is saved to the database?

So you could have something like this in your plugins init method:

```
craft()->on('assets.onBeforeSaveAsset', function(Event $event) {

    // Only rename if it’s a new asset being saved
    if($event->params[‘isNewAsset’])
    {
        $asset = $event->params[‘asset’];

        $asset->setAttribute(‘filename’, ‘SOME_RANDOM_STRING’);
    }
}
```

I haven’t tested this code, but from looking at Craft’s source and the docs this should work.

[Documentation about events can be found on the Craft website](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#events)

Comment: Hi @Alec-Ritson :) If you don't mind answering a probably dumb question, should I add something in 'SOME_RANDOM_STRING'?

Comment: Yes you would replace it with whatever random name you want to generate, like in your question: 2680542675157_cc7m541v_l.jpg

Comment: But that would generate a different random name for every image? Or that would do for one image only?

Comment: You would just need a way of generating a unique filename for each asset that's uploaded, so you could hash the initial filename then time stamp it, or you could look at [hashids](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php) for generating random hashes from id's (if there is a user id for example) it's just down to preference on how you want the filenames stored :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a terrible developer >.< Would be possible to use something like this for Craft? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3261107